# Error while assigning an attrs object class into other nested objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-attrs

I am having problem assigning the class `Private` into nested objects; the class validates the and converts a string into a `UUID` object. Or by default generates a `uuid1` if noting is passed.

```
class BadUUID(Exception):
    pass


def _convert(value) -> UUID:
    try:
        return value if isinstance(value, UUID) else UUID(value)
    except Exception as e:
        raise BadUUID(f"{value} cannot be converted to UUID!") from e


@define(slots=True, frozen=True)
class Private(UUID):
    uuid: UUID = field(
        default=uuid1(),
        converter=converters.optional(_convert),
        validator=validators.optional([validators.instance_of(UUID)]),
    )
```

---

Then I am trying to assign it to another class called `Session`:

```
@define(slots=True)
class Session:
    private: Private = field(
        default=Private(),
        converter=converters.optional(Private),
        validator=validators.optional([validators.instance_of(Private)]),
    )
```

---

```
print(Session("d283a713-9f4b-1c15-ab8d-9833336999ef"))
```

Result: `Session(private=Private(uuid=UUID('d283a713-9f4b-1c15-ab8d-9833336999ef')))`

This is correct.
This is with `Private(UUID)` inheriting `UUID`.

---

```
print(Session())
```

Result: `Session(private=Private(uuid=Private(uuid=UUID('8c3eb750-79fc-11ec-bfca-9833336444ef'))))`

This is wrong, should be `Session(private=Private(uuid=UUID('8c3eb750-79fc-11ec-bfca-9833336444ef'))))`

---

If I were to remove `UUID` from class `Private(UUID)` I get the following error for `print(Session())`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/+DEV/Python Snippets/uuid_demo/__init__.py", line 19, in _convert
    return value if isinstance(value, UUID) else UUID(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/uuid.py", line 174, in __init__
    hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
AttributeError: 'Private' object has no attribute 'replace'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/+DEV/Python Snippets/uuid_demo/session.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(Session())
  File "<attrs generated init __main__.Session>", line 3, in __init__
  File "/+DEV/Python Snippets/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/attr/converters.py", line 43, in optional_converter
    return converter(val)
  File "<attrs generated init uuid_demo.Private>", line 3, in __init__
  File "/+DEV/Python Snippets/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/attr/converters.py", line 43, in optional_converter
    return converter(val)
  File "/+DEV/Python Snippets/uuid_demo/__init__.py", line 21, in _convert
    raise BadUUID(f"{value} cannot be converted to UUID!") from e
uuid_demo.BadUUID: Private(uuid=UUID('56779226-79fd-11ec-8d54-9833336444ef')) cannot be converted to UUID!
```

---

Similarly if I then were to assign `Session` to another class `Test`:

```
@define(slots=True)
class Test:
    session: Session = field(
        default=Session().private,
        converter=converters.optional(Session),
        validator=validators.optional([validators.instance_of(Session)]),
    )


print(Test())
```

I get: `Test(session=Session(private=Private(uuid=Private(uuid=UUID('121e13c4-7a03-11ec-b8ec-784f436cb4ef')))))`

And it should be: `Test(session=Session(private=Private(uuid=UUID('121e13c4-7a03-11ec-b8ec-784f436cb4ef'))))`

This is also with with `Private(UUID)` inheriting `UUID`.

---

What am I doing wrong here?

Is there a better way to accomplish the job of `Private` in terms of converting/default value?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- `slots=True` is default with the NG APIs
- *all* instances of Private have the same default value. Is that on purpose? If not, you need to use `attrs.Factory(uuid1)`
- same goes for `Session.private`

The answer to your problem is that you have a converter set as `converter=converters.optional(Private)`. This means that any argument != None is *unconditionally* converted as `Private(argument)` – therefore wrapping it into a Private, including the default `Private()`.

I understand you want to take UUIDs are arguments and wrap them into `Private`s, but for that you'll have to catch if a `Private` is passed in.

*Or* you have an UUID as default:

```py
In [17]: @define
    ...: class Session:
    ...:     private: Private = field(
    ...:         default=Factory(uuid1),
    ...:         converter=converters.optional(Private),
    ...:         validator=validators.optional([validators.instance_of(Private)]),
    ...:     )

In [18]: Session()
Out[18]: Session(private=Private(uuid=UUID('5fd9c6cc-7a0c-11ec-8332-acde48001122')))
```